# From where to get ubuntu iso with latest upgrades?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, iso

I deploy ubuntu on multiple clients computers every day, currently I use 14.04.2 iso. After installing it I do `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` which takes some time.

Is there any 14.04.x iso which has the latest upgrade, so `apt-get upgrade` don't find any new packages?

My plan is to download this iso once a week, so at most I will download upgrades of a single week on each computer.

Mainly I am looking for ubunutu; but if there is for lubuntu, kubunutu and xbunut it will be great.

Comment: There are point releases like 14.04.1 and 14.04.2 on ubuntu.com but to expect them to release an ISO every time some package is updated is just crazy. You will inevitably need to update some

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternate to an updated ISO is to cache the debs your side.

You can use apt-mirror or apt-cacher to help speed things up,

### apt-mirror

apt-mirror will mirror an entire repository to your hard drive. You can then setup other computers to pull updates from this machine.

This is the most complete solution as all packages can be downloaded ready, but can involve a large download and a lot of disk space 150GB+ if you download, main, updates, restricted, universe and multiverse packages.

### apt-cacher

This is the product I use, it will cache only packages a machine has requested, I have it in SQUID proxy so when one machine downloads the deb any other machine trying to download that deb gets it from the squid cache.

### Where to get them

They are both in the standard repositories and can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-cacher
sudo apt-get install apt-mirror
```

Just googling found [this](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-and-apt-cacher) article that will get you going on getting it completed.

Comment: @markkirby updated with how to get them, they are in the repo.